# Update Garmin Nüvi 255 maps

Tags: updates, gps

Is there a way to update the GPS' (Garmin nüvi 255) maps with Ubuntu?

I'm hoping for a free (as in doesn't cost anything... I already bought the darn thing) solution.

I have installed the plugin, and it works with myGarmin, however I cannot register my device because I need to install whatever Windows software (Garmin Express) it requires, and all I can find is "Purchasing maps update"...

This is my first GPS and I just want to get the most recent maps as my local streets don't show up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a working solution for me. If this also work for other people, I'd like to know!

I went and got the maps from Open Street Map :

1. Backup the file `gmapprom.img` **from** your GPS device **to** your computer (just in case something goes wrong) using Nautilus.
2. Select the maps you want from [OpenStreetMap](http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/)
3. Download the `osm_generic_gmapsupp.zip` ("*Compressed file that contains a single image that can be placed directly onto the SD-card of the GPS.*") file
4. Extract the file `gmapsupp.img`, and rename it to `gmapprom.img`
5. With Nautilus, copy the extracted file on your device, replacing the old (backuped) `gmapprom.img` file.
6. Restart your GPS

The new maps even have extra points, like all the parks and playgrounds where I live.

Comment: +1 for the concise guide! Seems to have worked for my **Garmin nüvi 40**, but I'll need to do a bit more testing. Will write another comment if I run into trouble.